# Sql server gettime() with zero second

Tags: sql-server, getdate

how to SELECT GetDate() with zero second example: getdate() value `2017-09-19 09:35:51.340` but l need to select `2017-09-19 00:00:00.000` ?

Comment: do you need the seconds if they are going to be 00:00:00.000?

Comment: yes I need the seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date DATE= GETDATE();
SELECT CAST(@date AS DATETIME);
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```